# NGINX conditional secure_link

Tags: security, nginx, cookies, hyperlink, module

I'm writing an Nginx conf file for a reverse proxy server.

One of my location is protected by the Secure Link Module (http_secure_link_module).

But what I need is a conditional secure_link directive.

Something like that: if the URI contains the correct token, I'll be adding a Set-Cookie header like status=is_authorized and then just secure the link again if the user does not have the status cookie set.

```
location / {

    if ($cookie_STATUS = "IS_AUTHORIZED") {
       // if possible cancel secure_link for authorized (with cookie) users.
    }

secure_link $arg_token;
    secure_link_md5 "MD5_SECRET_PARAMETERS";

    set $token $arg_token;

    if ($secure_link = "") {
         return 403;
    }

    if ($secure_link = "0") {
        return 410;
    }

# Set Cokie
    add_header Set-Cookie STATUS=IS_AUTHORIZED;
    add_header Set-Cookie TOKEN=$arg_token;

# Rewrite rules
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/rewrite_rules.conf;        

    # Set Cache
    proxy_cache confluence_cache;
    include /usr/local/nginx/conf/cache.conf;
    # include /etc/nginx/shared/google_analytics.conf;

    # Confluence Authentication
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic BASE_64_HASH";
    proxy_pass PROXY_URL;
}
```

Can anyone help me achieve that? Basically I want to secure the link only for users who doesn't have the STATUS cookie set as IS_AUTHORIZED. Or secure_link only at the first page access.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do that with another variable inside my configuration file.

```
# if token is invalid nginx set $secure_link as empty string
    if ($secure_link = "") {
       set $is_allowed 'forbidden';
    }

    # if expiration time is gone nginx set $secure_link as 0
    if ($secure_link = "0") {
        set $is_allowed 'gone';
    }

    # if status cookie is set $is_allowed get 'authorized' as value
    if ($cookie_STATUS = "IS_AUTHORIZED") {
        set $is_allowed 'authorized';
    }

    # return 403 if $is_allowed = forbidden
    if ($is_allowed = 'forbidden') {
        return 403;
    }

    # return 410 if $is_allowed = gone
    if ($is_allowed = 'gone') {
        return 410;
    }
```

Then it proceed normally setting proxy, and other things.